# ROSJava Laserscan

Tags: laserscan, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi @ all

I'm trying to implement a 2D LaserScan in my App. I found the sensor_msgs.Laserscan and i want to print/show it into a ROSImageView. Unfortunately there is no sample tutorial and maybe someone has implemented this function yet. So, now i'm trying to implement it but if there is someone, who has a solution i, yeees it would be nice! =)

Greeting

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10069/rosjava-laserscan/) by [Mr_Miyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/599/mr_miyagi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-05-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used ROSImageView yet, but a quick look suggests that is is solely intended to be used with images (similar to image_view). By creating an image out of a laser scan (which could be done in various more or less hacky ways) it could be abused to display a laser scan.

AFAIK there is no built-in laser scan visualization available for ROSJava yet.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-08-01**:
FYI, this is no longer the case. The VisualizationView and LaserScanLayer will display laser scans.